# SQL statement translation

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL, and this is my first try to translate to SQL this kind of statement.

> Find the drinkers that frequent all the bars that serve a beer John Smith likes

And I have the following three tables to answer it:

```
FREQUENTS(DRINKER, BAR) 
SERVES(BAR, BEER) 
LIKES(DRINKER, BEER)
```

This was my unsuccessful approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F1.DRINKER
FROM FREQUENTS F1
WHERE F1.DRINKER<>'John Smith'
AND   F1.DRINKER NOT IN(SELECT F2.DRINKER
                        FROM FREQUENTS F2
                    WHERE F2.BAR NOT IN (SELECT S.BAR 
                                        FROM SERVES S, LIKES L
                                        WHERE L.DRINKER='John Smith'
                                        AND S.BEER=L.BEER
                                        AND L.DRINKER=F2.DRINKER))
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to run it? What error do you get? (apart from the fact that JOINs would be the proper way to go, I don't currently see the problem without the error message...)

Comment: no error, just empty table.... and there is a tuple that should be shown, but I just get an empty table

Comment: Can you please supply sample table data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT F1.DRINKER
FROM FREQUENTS F1 
WHERE F1.BAR IN (SELECT S.BAR FROM SERVES S, LIKES L
                                    WHERE L.DRINKER='John Smith'
                                    AND S.BEER=L.BEER)
```

I have removed the extra subquery which you have created

Comment: >[Error] Script lines: 1-8 --------------------------
 ORA-00903: invalid table name
 Script line 3, statement line 3, column 1

Comment: @@user2108393-pl. post sample data and desired output if you expect more then some general example. Not everyone has time and will to build sample data for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.  It's not exactly elegant and if the data gets updated during the execution of this code, then this may not work but here it is

```
DECLARE @bars TABLE (bar nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @drinkers TABLE (drinker nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @drinkerCounts TABLE (count int, drinker nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @barCount int

insert into @bars
select distinct bar from serves where beer in
(select beer from likes where drinker = 'John Smith')

select @barCount = COUNT(*) from @bars

insert into @drinkers
select drinker from frequents f
inner join @bars b on f.bar = b.bar
where drinker <> 'John Smith'

insert into @drinkerCounts
select count(drinker), drinker
from @drinkers
group by drinker

select * from @drinkerCounts dc
where dc.Count = @barCount
```

Comment: @@Sachin Kainth - please use proper syntax. Your example is not valid as is. This will never compile in Oracle and may confuse users... This is regarding syntax only, not code.

Comment: @Art, sorry, I assumed it was SQL Server.  It is only later on that I realised that this was for Oracle.  In SQL Server this both compiles and is functional.  Perhaps you could this to use Oracle syntax.